# Non-renewing subscriptions that are non-sharable across user's devices

Tags: ios, subscription, in-app-purchase

I wish to implement IAP within my iOS app, offering a push notification service for a period of time. This seems to fit under the category of non-renewing subscriptions. One requirement from Apple is

> You are required to deliver non-renewing subscriptions to all devices
>   owned by the user. Non-renewing subscriptions are not automatically
>   synchronized to all devices by Store Kit; you must implement this
>   infrastructure yourself. For example, most subscriptions are provided
>   by an external server; your server would need to implement a mechanism
>   to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user
>   who purchased them.

However, I don't want this subscription to be shared across all user's devices (as there is extra cost for pushing notification on additional devices). Does my app's requirement violate the Apple's requirement above? Has anyone experienced any issues similar to what I will do?

Answer (score 0):

Any subscription MUST be restorable to any device that is associated with the user's Apple ID.  The subscription is to the Apple ID, not the device.  You will be rejected unless you comply completely to this rule.

There's nothing you can do; Apple is very strict on this provision.